reduce payment link to send via whatsapp api
In Brazil we have the PIX payment method, which generates a copy and paste key from a link, but it is too long to send via Whatsapp, I need to shorten the link.
We use the API WHATSAPP  to send the messagens. How we can reduce the link
have the link reduced
